# Interpretation of Saturated Model vs. Model with Interaction and One Main Effect

Tags: regression, interaction, least-squares

Say that I have two regressions:

1) $Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X_i + \alpha_2 X_i*Z_i + \epsilon_i$

2) $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \beta_2 Z_i + \beta_3 X_i*Z_i + \epsilon_i$

$X_i$ and $Z_i$ are both binary variables. $Y_i$ is continuous.

How do the interpretations of the estimated coefficients differ between 1) and 2)?  Specifically, how should I interpret $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_3$?

Comment: One way to approach this would be to recognize that if you use $1,-1$ coding for the variables (instead of the usual $1,0$), then $W_i = X_iZ_i$ also is a $1,-1$ binary variable and $Z_i = X_iW_i$: that makes model (1) a standard additive model for $Y$ in terms of $X$ and $W$ and model (2) is the same thing with the $X*W$ interaction included (with coefficient $\beta_2$). Presumably that's familiar territory for you and you are comfortable interpreting the coefficients. (If not, search our site: there are plenty of threads about interpreting interactions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throughout my answer, the usual conditional mean independence
$\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_{i}\vert X_{i},Z_{i})=0$ is maintained.

It is instructive to consider a concrete
example. Let $X_{i}$ be a dummy of college education, such that $X_{i}=1$
if worker $i$ is a college graduate, and $X_{i}=0$ otherwise; and let $Z_{i}$
be a dummy of gender, such that $Z_{i}=1$ if $i$ is male, and $0$
if $i$ is female. And suppose $Y_{i}$ is the observed income. Hence
$\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=1)$ is the expected income of
a male college graduate, and $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=0)$
is the expected income of a female college graduate. Other conditional
expectations, such as $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0$), have
similar interpretations.

First, it is not hard to verify that the coefficients $\alpha_{2}$
equals to 
$$
\alpha_{2}=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=0).
$$
This is the difference of the expected income of male and female college
graduates. The significance of $\alpha_{2}$ may indicate gender discrimination
among college graduates.

Next, we have
$$
\beta_{2}+\beta_{3}=\alpha_{2}=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=0).
$$
And
$$
\beta_{0}+\beta_{2}=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=1),\ \beta_{0}=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0).
$$
So 
$$
\beta_{2}=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0),
$$
which measures the gender discrimination among workers without college
degrees. And $\beta_{3}=(\beta_{2}+\beta_{3})-\beta_{2}$, that is
$$
\beta_{3}=\{\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=1,Z_{i}=0)\}-\{\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=1)-\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0)\}.
$$
So $\beta_{3}$ can be understood the difference of the magnitudes
of gender discrimination in two cohorts, workers *with* college
education and workers *without* college degree. The positive sign
of $\beta_{3}$ indicates that the gender discrimation among higher
educated workers is greater than it is in less educated workers.

Last but not least, **one important assumption made implicitly
by model (1)** is the following
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0)=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=1)=\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0)=\alpha_{0}.
$$
That is by specifying model (1), one has assumed that there is no
wage discrimination against gender for those who have no college degree.
The expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=0)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i}\vert X_{i}=0,Z_{i}=1)$
are the expected income of female and male worker without college
education, respectively. Such an assumption in general may or may
not hold, depending on your empirical exercise.